# IOS Can I get users information about Who bought my product in In-app purchase?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, inappsettingskit

I have a live application, in this application, I have Non-Consumable products but I want to know who bought which product. I just want information about the users. 
I have checked in **App analytics** and **Sales and Trends**
The problem arises is that some of the users buy a product but not able to get so I just want Information from that why the user will not able to get the product. Users iPhone have a detail that he buys, but how can I check from my end. Please help me Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

There are several possibilities that the user might face if they are not able to use the purchased products. I am listing few ones:

1. Transaction failed by the server.
2. Connection to iTunes Store get failed.
3. User cancelled the subscription.

To avoid any such scenarios, you should always follow the [best practices](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2387/_index.html) given by the apple.

Also its good to validate the receipt from the app store. You can get more details over [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateRemotely.html).

Comment: thanks for the response but you didn't get my question. I am not talking about programming. I have highlighted the words in boldface check it. How can I check which user have bought my product I just want info of users.